# How to root android device, Emulator?

Tags: android

I'm making an android application in which I want to show Punjabi text in my view. Most people told me we can add different fonts through rooting. After that I'm able to show Punjabi text in device.

How can I root my emulator or android device so I can show Punjabi font in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a custom font to your application you must create a folder named fonts inside your assets folder. Put your .ttf font file inside this folder. Then use the following code to initialize your font.

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font.ttf");
```

To apply this typeface to any TextView use:

```
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes,i had already done this but still it shows boxes somewhere i had used the file(AnmolUni.ttf). It shows me Punjabi font but still it shows boxes somewhere..

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR, you are root in emulator by default.

```
me@mymachine:~$ adb shell
root@android:/ #
```

Comment: where i write this commaand can you describe this

Comment: Run emulator. Then in your console (in windows that is StartMenu-Run...-type "cmd"-enter; in linux you know where your console is) type `adb shell`. You should get a prompt from emulator shell. If it ends with "#" - you are already root. But your question, I believe, is not about being root.